# Initial column sort function not working as expected

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort the 5th column on page load without clicking anything. I can sort the table by clicking the headers but adding this option isn't working for me. I have v2.23.2.

The column I want to sort has numbers, and I want the largest number to be at the top, so descending sort.

```
$("#table").tablesorter({
    sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    sortList: [4,0]
});
```

Right now, it is sorting with ascension on page load, but that's the default setting and I don't know why it's not working.

Thanks in advance Mottie :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sortList: [4,1]
```

A sort value of `0` specifies ascending. You want `1` for descending.

> An array of instructions for per-column sorting and direction in the format: [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ] where columnIndex is a zero-based index for your columns left-to-right and sortDirection is 0 for Ascending and 1 for Descending. A valid argument that sorts ascending first by column 1 and then column 2 looks like: [[0,0],[1,0]]

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#api

Comment: +1 but he did mention he was using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which has the same settings for the `sortList` option ;)

Comment: I don't see anything about a fork. Enlighten me. Same as what?

Comment: The original version is stuck at v2.0.5 ([repo](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter)). I made a fork a few years back... it's now at v2.24.5 ([repo](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)). I was saying `sortList` hadn't changed, but there are improvements to the usage of [`sortAppend`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortappend) (which doesn't even work in v2.0.5 - [ref](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#sortAppend)) and triggering a [`sorton` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sorton).

Comment: I see. So is my answer incorrect, or do you suggest different doc references?

Comment: Also, @chickachickayeah mentions using `v2.23.2` and thanked me in advance LOL

Comment: No, you're answer is good. It still works in both versions. I tried to maintain compatibility with the original as much as possible.

Comment: Understood. To be fair, those are fairly vague hints. :)